# How to specify the amount of numbers needed in a range with user input

Tags: python, python-3.x, input, user-input

I need the user input to specify the amount of numbers to be printed in the range.
I have the following code for that:

```
i = 0;
start_char = 65
end_char = 65
x = input("Enter numbers of plates:")
while (i < int(x)):
     if i%26 == 0 and i!= 0:
            end_char = (65)
            start_char += 1

            print((chr(start_char))+(chr(end_char)))
            end_char =end_char + 1
            i = i + 1
     for plate_code in (range(1000)):
         print(str(plate_code)  + ((chr(start_char))+(chr(end_char))))
```

Comment: What't the problem that you're having?

Comment: Maybe you want to try a little more high level approach with `ascii_uppercase` from the `string` module and `product()` and `islice()` from the `itertools` module. The outer loop then starts with `for start_char, end_char in islice(product(ascii_uppercase, ascii_uppercase), int(x)):`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are incrementing `i` only inside of `if` and since `i = 0` initially, your code never enters `if` and stucks in an infinite loop.

Move `i = i + 1` outside of `if`.

```
while (i < int(x)):
     if i%26 == 0 and i!= 0:
            end_char = (65)
            start_char += 1

            print((chr(start_char))+(chr(end_char)))
            end_char =end_char + 1
     i = i + 1  #move incrementation outside of if
     for plate_code in (range(1000)):
         print(str(plate_code)  + ((chr(start_char))+(chr(end_char))))
```

Comment: I'm quite sure this isn't enough and incrementing `end_char` should also be outside the ``if``.  Also it is still reinventing the `for` loop with `while`.

Answer (score 0):

Just don't try to reinvent `for` loops:

```
def main():
    start_char = end_char = 65
    plate_count = int(input('Enter numbers of plates:'))
    for i in range(plate_count):
        if i and i % 26 == 0:
            end_char = 65
            start_char += 1
        print(chr(start_char) + chr(end_char))
        end_char += 1
        for plate_code in range(1000):
            print('{}{}{}'.format(plate_code, chr(start_char), chr(end_char)))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Alternativly make use of the power of the standard library:

```
from itertools import islice, product
from string import ascii_uppercase


def main():
    plate_count = int(input('Enter numbers of plates: '))
    for start_char, end_char in islice(
        product(ascii_uppercase, ascii_uppercase), plate_count
    ):
        print('{}{}'.format(start_char, end_char))
        for plate_code in range(1000):
            print('{}{}{}'.format(plate_code, start_char, end_char))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```